# What is the parent of the layout element?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development so this might be an obvious question, but I've looked at multiple sources and can't find the answer.  If you put widget elements inside a layout element then the parent of those widget elements is the layout element, right? So what is the parent element of the layout? Because in the default generated file, activity_main.xml (for the layout), there is the attribute **android:layout_width="match_parent"** for the topmost constraint layout element. So, **what is the parent of this constraint layout element?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ConstraintLayout` is the root layout of your `Activity` but it is just part of a layout created by the system.

You can for example get the reference of the parent layout of your `ConstraitLayout`:

```
ViewGroup layoutRoot = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

When you set `match_parent`, your `View` (a Layout is a `ViewGroup` which is just a `View`) will try to fill the space available in its parent layout. So, in a certain way, it just tell to how much your view can grow in the X/Y-axis. In your case, your `ConstraintLayout` will grow in order to match that `android.R.id.content`

Of course, there's one View on the top of the stack (probably the `decorView` of your `Window`) which is created by the System and is assuming whole area available on the `Window` created by the system.

Comment: Thanks for the all responses

Answer (score 0):

Basically we use parent layout as Linear Layout/Relative Layou/ConstraintLayout/Frame Layout etc. So all are classes which extends ViewGroup. Please refer to Google developer documentation for better understanding.

Read this -

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

`match_parent` is a fixed value for views to stretch according to their parents.
For example let's say you have a Textview inside a RelativeLayout. If the Textview is set to match parent then it would stretch according to its parent/rootview which is the Relative layout.

So basically it would have as the same height and width as the parent layout.